# How to have access to a JSON file without declaring a variable reffering to it

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, geolocation

I am working on  a django project and want to have access in a JSON file in order to do a geolocation process with the data from the JSON to my template.

The JSON resides in **project/static/test/data.js**

And it has the below data:

```
var json= {"count":6,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"title":"Name1","date":"2018-10-02","products":"","categories":"","client_id":{"id":500,"client_id":"3000-3333","title":"Name1","lat":"40.2323","lng":"34.232323","address":"address1","address_no":"","region":"region1","tk":"34343","municipality":"municipality1","department":"department1","description":null,"categories":null,"phone":"2323232332"},"pcategory":"","product_team":""},{"title":Name2....
```

My script in my template resides in **project/templates/test/test_template_json.html**

And it has the below script:

```
<script>

// Initialize and add the map

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom:8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.232323,23.72752323239)
      });

//json is the whole document and results is the list with the json objects

for (var x in json.results){
  var client=json.results[x].client_id;
  var location =new google.maps.LatLng(client.lat,client.lng);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:location,
    map:map});
}
}
</script>
```

If i use the variable: var **json**={"count":6,"next":null,.... };

in my data.js file for accessing my json i do not have any problem.

But I want **not** to declare the var json and still be able to access my json in the test_template_json.html file.

In other words **how can i access my json if this has the format**:

```
{"count":6,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"title":...
```

How can I do it? Any ideas?

Comment: You could place the JSON in a file and request it using Ajax.

Comment: @schwaber yes this could be a solution,like this:var table = $('#clients').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                ajax:   {
                    url:  "/project/static/test/data.js?format=json",
                    cache: true,
                    dataSrc: function (json) {
                    var return_data = new Array();
                    console.log(json);
                    if (json.results.length==0){

                        $('#alert').show();
                        $('#map').hide();
                    }     But without ajax call?

Comment: You could try using sync XHR, but why not throw all the dependent code into the Ajax callback method?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a research period I came up to a solution that worked.The below snippets are in Javascript.

**Step 1)** Define a XMLHttpRequest object and pass into the open() function the path referring to the json.

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    // xobj.open('GET', '/static/test/download2.json', true);
    xobj.open('GET', 'path/path..../path', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
 }
```

**Step 2)** Parse the response from loadJSON with `JSON.parse(response)` , so now you have access to the json data through a javascript variable(`var actual_JSON`).

```
loadJSON(function(response) {
  // Parse JSON string into object
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
    for (var x in actual_JSON){
  var client=actual_JSON[x].client_id;
  var location =new google.maps.LatLng(client.lat,client.lng);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:location,
    map:map});

}
 });
```

Then you can easily access the data using a for loop.

A useful article on loading a json file can be found here:https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript